# How to StartEdit in EditingPlugin in grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I know row index and column name. But `EditingPlugin` need

```
startEdit( Ext.data.Model record, Ext.data.Model columnHeader )</code>.
```

How I can take it and give it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record you can do

```
record = grid.getStore().getAt(recordIndex);
```

but for the column header, I dont' think you needed it since startedit requeres the column not its header. In the CellEditing plugin doc it says column header but it describes it as the column object.

columnHeader : Ext.data.Model
The Column object defining the column to be edited

Provide a more detailed example giving the available local variables and I will try to gieve a solution for the column also.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column index you can also do this:

```
 cellEditor.startEditByPosition({row:0,column:0})
```